# Python: Return doesn't work but Print works

Tags: python, function, dictionary, switch-statement, return

The point of the library I'm creating is to return the Hexadecimal value of a colour when you enter the name of the colour.

The above program works fine with print although it doesn't return a value as soon as **print** is replaced with **return**.
But the entire point of returning a value is gone as it can not be used in conjunction with other programs.
return("#F2F3F4") doesn't work

And yes **I tried it without the brackets** and it doesn't make any difference.
Hope you can figure out the problem. Thank you in advance!

```
class ColourConst():
    def __init__(self, colour):
        col = ""
        #Shades of White
        def Anti_flash_white():
             print("#F2F3F4")

        def Antique_white():
            print("#FAEBD7")

        def Beige():
            print("#F5F5DC")

        def Blond():
            print("#FAF0BE")

        ColourCon = {
        #Shades of White
        "Anti-flash white": Anti_flash_white, 
        "Antique white": Antique_white,
        "Beige": Beige,
        "Blond" : Blond
        }
        myfunc = ColourCon[colour]
        myfunc()

ColourConst("Anti-flash white")
```

Comment: Fix the editing

Comment: you are missing the `self` as first argument of all your methods (or the `@staticmehod` decorator?). you never instantiate a `ColourConst` object. and there is no point in having all these functions in a class.

Comment: It _does_ return a value if you use `return`, but it does not print it if you don't also use `print`. Also, unless this is an exercise in functional programming, why not just have a `dict` mapping color names to color codes directly instead of using those intermediate inner functions?

Comment: return doesnt mean print

Answer (score 2):

It *does* return a value if you use `return`, but unless you also use `print`, it won't *print* it.

```
class ColourConst():
    def __init__(self, colour):
        def Anti_flash_white():
            return "#F2F3F4" # return here
        def Antique_white():
            return "#FAEBD7" # and here
        def Beige():
            return "#F5F5DC" # and here
        def Blond():
            return "#FAF0BE" # you get the point...
        ColourCon = {
            "Anti-flash white": Anti_flash_white, 
            "Antique white": Antique_white,
            "Beige": Beige,
            "Blond" : Blond
        }
        myfunc = ColourCon[colour]
        print(myfunc()) # add print here

ColourConst("Anti-flash white")
```

Having said that, this is a pretty horrible way of doing this. First, this is the constructor of a class, which by definition can only return the newly created instance of that class, `self`. Instead, you can just make it a function returning the value, and print the value when you call the function, making it much more reusable. Also, instead of mapping color names to functions, each returning the value, you can just map names to values directly.

```
def colour_const(name):
    colour_codes = {
        "Anti-flash white": "#F2F3F4", 
        "Antique white": "#FAEBD7",
        "Beige": "#F5F5DC",
        "Blond" : "#FAF0BE"
    }
    return colour_codes.get(name, "unknown color")

print(colour_const("Anti-flash white"))
```

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k although I'm trying to completely get rid of print so this library I'm working on can be used in conjunction with other libraries like for example matplotlib. And why have you used `get`.

Comment: @SavL Then you should use the second variant with the single function. Here, the `print` is not part of the function (the library) but of the code that's using the function/library.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad you have used the print outside the function. Can you pls explain by you have you used `get`.

Comment: @SavL `get` will not raise an exception if the key is not present in the dict but instead return `None` or the provided default value. Depending on the use case, either raising an exception, or returning None, or some default value (e.g. pure white #FFFFFF) might be best. Just wanted to show that there are other options.